# Sorting of characters in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`, in which I want to sort one column (`var`) which is a character column. I used the following code:

```
df$var=order(as.character(df$var))
```

this line of code runs with no error, but changes the values of the column to numeric data type.

Comment: Try `sort(df$var)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- iris[sample(nrow(iris),5),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 40           5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
# 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica
# 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa

# what you tried returns numeric because order does
order(as.character(df$Species)) # [1] 5 3 4 1 2

# This "works" but sorts, the vector only, not the df
sort(as.character(df$Species)) #[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "versicolor" "virginica"  "virginica"

# This sorts the df
df[order(df$Species),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
# 98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
# 93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor
# 135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica
# 141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica
```